# How to lock keyboard to Simplified Chinese Handwriting?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, ios8.3

I want to lock my keyboard to just simplified chinese handwriting. How do I do this?

The problem is that I am trying to create a Chinese quiz app in Xcode 6 using swift and I want the quiz-takers to write in the character to match the English word using a chinese handwriting keyboard. 
I do not know how to program this and other questions asked like this do not seem to yield a useful result for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't lock the keyboard unless you present your own custom keyboard. Once again, you have to take into account those with physical keyboards as well (who can bypass your custom keyboard).

A good recommendation is to use a custom handwriting recogniser that links to a label (to prevent keyboard intervention).